# Scaling Down Replicas On Completion Without Termination

Tags: kubernetes, queue, message-queue, amazon-eks

I'm using Kubernetes replicas to run 'run-to-completion' tasks.

I currently increase the number of replicas when we have a work item to complete on a queue and the container immediately consumes the item. As the desired replicas has never changed, Kubernetes kicks off a new replica which then finds that there's nothing to do and so terminates immediately (and repeat). If I scale down the replicas before a container has finished (i.e. as soon as a queue item is consumed), one of the replicas that are doing work terminates prematurely.

Is there a way to reduce the replicas and not enforce termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `termination grace period` for all pods so when container terminates it's wait for some time.

you can also add the SIG term in lifecycle also that particular pod donot take next item from queue.

```
lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              # SIGTERM triggers a quick exit; gracefully terminate instead
              command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]
```

you can also have look at this : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Comment: Thanks Harsh  - I had a feeling this was the only solution but I can’t help feel like it’s the epitomy of janky

Comment: yes probably you have to develope smart application as per need or write consumer that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself in the same situation as me, have a look at Argo: https://argoproj.github.io/argo/